# how to validate multiple input jquery repeater in laravel 6

Tags: laravel

I would like to validate my form using jquery repater and how to get value

this is my input :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="test_1_qty" placeholder="0" data-name="qty" name="test[1][qty]">
```

this is my controller :

```
$rules  = [
            'qty'       => 'required',

        ];
$message = [
           
            'qty.required' => 'This field is Required',
        ];
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules,$message);
```

Comment: You are showing us code which validates using laravel and asking for `jquery.repeater`. Show us what you've tried for `jquery.repeater` and what is not working

Comment: sorry i using validate laravel, i dont understand how to validate in laravel

Answer (score 1):

You are getting your `qty` field from an array that is `test`

```
$rules  = [
            'test.*.qty'       => 'required',
        ];

$message = [
            'test.*.qty.required' => 'This field is Required'
        ];
```

Comment: how to get value from the input ?

Comment: You can loop over the request parameter. `$input = $request->all();`. Now you can use `$input['test']`. It will give you the all values of `qty`. you can loop over it.